# IE7 and flowplayer 5.2.0 fails with "flash: Video file not found"

Tags: flash, audio, video, internet-explorer-7, flowplayer

I use flowplayer to play movies and hear audio without problems in Firefox, Google Chrome, iPad3, IE9, IE8.

But IE7 fails with: `flash: Video file not found`

**I have this in** `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/js/flowplayer/skin/minimalist.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/flowplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
flowplayer.conf.embed = false;
</script>
```

**Video markup:**

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-embed="false">
   <video preload="none">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="/video/test.mp4"/>
      <source type="video/ogg" src="/video/test.ogv"/>
      <source type="video/flash" src="/video/test.mp4"/>
   </video>
</div>
```

- FLASH version: 11.5.502.110
- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

It seems the path needs to be complete paths. That means

`/video/test.mp4` becomes `http://www.mydomain.com/video/test.mp4`

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-embed="false">
   <video preload="none">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.mydomain.com/video/test.mp4"/>
      <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.mydomain.com/video/test.ogv"/>
      <source type="video/flash" src="http://www.mydomain.com/video/test.mp4"/>
   </video>
</div>
```